# Failed cyborg suicide attempt?

Tags: story-identification, comics

I remember reading a gritty black and white comic strip in Dutch in the (probably early) 1990s featuring a man using a gun to shoot himself in the head, but ending up cussing as the bullet got stuck in the metal part on the right side of his head.

I thought it might be [Mean Machine](http://www.2000ad.org/?zone=thrill&page=profiles&choice=MEANMAC) but he doesn't look very capable of using a gun with his right arm.

Comment: Was that all there was to the story, of was that only a small part of it?

Comment: I think it were no more than 4 panels on the bottom row of a right page of a European comic album ([40-60 pages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_comics)).

Answer (score 3):

There is a scene like this in "Ranxerox" the graphic series by Liberatore and Tamburini, which is very shock value loaded. It's inclusion in the HEAVY METAL adult comic magazine in the US was very controversial for multiple reasons - not so much the causal violence as black humor, but the fact that the android protagonist was having an on-again, off-again love affair with a precocious 15 YO girl.
Anyway, with his human emotions, Ranxerox is susceptible to bouts of depression and does try to commit suicide, which all fail as he is programmed to consider himself human and using methods that would end a human life do not work on him.( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RanXerox for a rather short and "artsy" article. )

Comment: Interesting, but i couldn't find any suicide attempts. He lives to serve Lubna.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure it was him, but [Deathlok](https://longboxgraveyard.com/tag/deathlok/) certainly comes close to what i remember:

> The original Deathlok debuted in Astonishing Tales #25, in a wildly
>   exuberant tale from Rich Buckler and Doug Moench, in which dead
>   soldier Luther Manning found himself resurrected as a badass cyborg
>   killing machine — and wasn’t happy about it, arguing with the computer
>   in his head, and futilely questing to recover his lost humanity.

He's cruel and gritty, and the writers are not without humor, but so far i've only found this attempt:

[image: Deathlok failed suicide attempt]